# How to find NullPointerException

Tags: android, view-helpers

here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.translate_activity);
    mFromEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    mToEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.translation);
    mFromButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.from);
    mToButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.to);
    mTranslateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_translate);
    mSwapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_swap);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    //
    // Install the language adapters on both the From and To spinners.
    //
    //****************this is line 132 from the error log************************************//
    mFromButton.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
    mToButton.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);

    mTranslateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSwapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFromEditText.selectAll();

    connectToTranslateService();
}
******************************************************************************************
```

here is log.txt (the error i get):

```
06-19 18:11:39.171: D/AndroidRuntime(1899): Shutting down VM
06-19 18:11:39.171: W/dalvikvm(1899): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.SmsTranslate/org.example.SmsTranslate.TranslateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at org.example.SmsTranslate.TranslateActivity.onCreate(TranslateActivity.java:132)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-19 18:11:39.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1899):     ... 11 more    

*************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and check mFromButton and mOnClickListener.  Which one is null?

Comment: You'll be stuck for another 2 months if you don't help us to help you!

Comment: Michal, the log is not useful since you told us what the error is and at which line it happens.  What is useful is to know what is null so please, put a breakpoint on that line and inspect each variable.  Which one is null?

Comment: i puted a bp on this line, how can i know if the variable is null??

Comment: i have inserteda space in line 132 and i am still getting the same mistake! line 132, how could that be??

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you think that a space would stop a nullpointerexception?  Where exactly did you put the space?  To see the value of the variables, just look in the debugger window.  Are you using Eclipse? Window > Open Perspective > Debug

Comment: i have changed the number of lines by mistake, so inline 132 there was a space, and i still get the same error, instead of exapting the error would be now in line 136 where the line is right now...

Comment: anyone?? :( steel no answere

Comment: We don't now what line 136 is.  Please edit your question and clearly indicate which is line 136.

Comment: line 132:    mFromButton.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);        mFromButton is NULL, what can i do ?

Comment: So `mFromButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.from);` must be returning null.  Check that you have a button, with the id `from` in `translate_activity`